# Count number of days each employee take vacation in a month SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this table:

**Vacationtbl**:

```
    ID   Start      End
    -------------------------
    01   04/10/17   04/12/17
    01   04/27/17   05/02/17
    02   04/13/17   04/15/17
    02   04/17/17   04/20/17
    03   06/14/17   06/22/17

Employeetbl:

ID   Fname   Lname
------------------
01   John    AAA
02   Jeny    BBB
03   Jeby    CCC
```

I like to count the number of days each employee take vacation in April.

My query:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(DATEDIFF(DAY, Start, End) + 1) AS Days 
FROM 
    Vacationtbl
GROUP BY 
    ID
```

- `01` returns `9` (not correct)
- `02` returns `7` (correct)

How do I fix the query so that it counts until the end of month and stops at end of month. For example, April has 30 days. On second row, Employee `01` should counts `4/27/17` until `4/30/17`. And `05/02/17` is for May.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Tally/Calendar table is the way to go.  However, you can use an **ad-hoc** tally table.

**Example**

```
Select Year  = Year(D)
      ,Month = Month(D)
      ,ID
      ,Days  = count(*)
 From  Vacationtbl A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Top (DateDiff(DAY,[Start],[End])+1) D=DateAdd(DAY,-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select Null)),[Start]) 
                 From  master..spt_values 
             ) B
 -- YOUR OPTIONAL WHERE STATEMENT HERE --
 Group By ID,Year(D),Month(D)
 Order By 1,2,3
```

**Returns**

```
Year    Month   ID  Days
2017    4       01  7
2017    4       02  7
2017    5       01  2
```

> **EDIT - To Show All ID even if Zero Days**

```
Select ID
      ,Year  = Year(D)
      ,Month = Month(D)
      ,Days  = sum(case when D between [Start] and [End] then 1 else 0 end)
 From (
       Select Top (DateDiff(DAY,'05/01/2017','05/31/2017')+1) D=DateAdd(DAY,-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select Null)),'05/01/2017')  
        From  master..spt_values 
      ) D
 Cross Join Vacationtbl  B
 Group By ID,Year(D),Month(D)
 Order By 1,2,3
```

**Returns**

```
ID  Year    Month   Days
1   2017    5       2
2   2017    5       0
```

**[dbFiddle if it Helps](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=d2c0ca047b4cb6892be0317b691fecf8)**

> **EDIT - 2 Corrects for Overlaps (Gaps and Islands)**

```
--Create Some Sample Data
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Declare @Vacationtbl Table ([ID] varchar(50),[Start] date,[End] date)
Insert Into @Vacationtbl Values
 (01,'04/10/17','04/12/17')
,(01,'04/27/17','05/02/17')
,(02,'04/13/17','04/15/17')
,(02,'04/17/17','04/20/17')
,(02,'04/16/17','04/17/17')  -- << Overlap
,(03,'05/16/17','05/17/17')

-- The Actual Query
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Select ID
      ,Year  = Year(D)
      ,Month = Month(D)
      ,Days  = sum(case when D between [Start] and [End] then 1 else 0 end)
 From (Select Top (DateDiff(DAY,'04/01/2017','04/30/2017')+1) D=DateAdd(DAY,-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select Null)),'04/01/2017')  From  master..spt_values ) D
 Cross Join (
                Select ID,[Start] = min(D),[End] = max(D)
                 From (
                        Select E.*,Grp = Dense_Rank() over (Order By D) - Row_Number() over (Partition By ID Order By D)
                         From (
                                Select Distinct A.ID,D
                                  From  @Vacationtbl A
                                  Cross Apply (Select Top (DateDiff(DAY,A.[Start],A.[End])+1) D=DateAdd(DAY,-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select Null)),A.[Start]) From  master..spt_values ) B
                               ) E
                      ) G
                 Group By ID,Grp    
            )  B
 Group By ID,Year(D),Month(D)
 Order By 1,2,3
```

**Returns**

```
ID  Year    Month   Days
1   2017    4       7
2   2017    4       8
3   2017    4       0
```

Comment: @JennyTran If this truly helped, you can ACCEPT the answer

Comment: Hi John, did I accept the answer already? I don't know how to do that? I just clicked on the upper arrow on the top? Is that right? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Without a dates table, you could use

```
select Id
     ,sum(case when [end]>'20170430' and [start]<'20170401' then datediff(day,'20170401','20170430')+1
               when [end]>'20170430' then datediff(day,[start],'20170430')+1
               when [start]<'20170401' then datediff(day,'20170401',[end])+1
          else datediff(day,[start],[end])+1
        end) as VacationDays
from Vacationtbl
where [start] <= '20170430' and [end] >= '20170401'
group by Id
```

There are 3 conditions here

- Start is before this month and the end is after this month. In this case you subtract the end and start dates of the month.
- End is after month end and start is in the month, in this case subtract month end date from the start.
- Start is before this month but the end is in the month. In this case subtract month start date and the end date.

Edit: Based on the OP's comments that the future dates have to be included,

```
/*This recursive cte generates the month start and end dates with in a given time frame
For Eg: all the month start and end dates for 2017
Change the start and end period as needed*/
with dates (month_start_date,month_end_date) as 
(select cast('2017-01-01' as date),cast(eomonth('2017-01-01') as date)
 union all
 select dateadd(month,1,month_start_date),eomonth(dateadd(month,1,month_start_date))  from dates
 where month_start_date < '2017-12-01'
)
--End recursive cte
--Query logic is the same as above
select v.Id
,year(d.month_start_date) as yr,month(d.month_start_date) as mth
,sum(case when v.[end]>d.month_end_date and v.[start]<d.month_start_date then datediff(day,d.month_start_date,d.month_end_date)+1
          when v.[end]>d.month_end_date then datediff(day,v.[start],d.month_end_date)+1
          when v.[start]<d.month_start_date then datediff(day,d.month_start_date,v.[end])+1
     else datediff(day,v.[start],v.[end])+1
     end) as VacationDays
from dates d
join Vacationtbl v on v.[start] <= d.month_end_date and v.[end] >= d.month_start_date
group by v.id,year(d.month_start_date),month(d.month_start_date)
```

Comment: It's dynamic. How do I make it for 12 months and advanced months in the future?

Comment: 7 for 2 employees

Comment: that us what this query does.i am asking about the future months output.

Comment: For May 2017, Employee 01  has 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Calendar or dates table for this sort of thing.

For only 152kb in memory, you can have 30 years of dates in a table with this:

```
/* dates table */
declare @fromdate date = '20000101';
declare @years    int  = 30;
/* 30 years, 19 used data pages ~152kb in memory, ~264kb on disk */
;with n as (select n from (values(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) t(n))
select top (datediff(day, @fromdate,dateadd(year,@years,@fromdate)))
    [Date]=convert(date,dateadd(day,row_number() over(order by (select 1))-1,@fromdate))
into dbo.Dates
from n as deka cross join n as hecto cross join n as kilo
               cross join n as tenK cross join n as hundredK
order by [Date];
create unique clustered index ix_dbo_Dates_date
  on dbo.Dates([Date]);
```

Without taking the actual step of creating a table, you can use it inside a [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) with just this:

```
declare @fromdate date = '20170401';
declare @thrudate date = '20170430';
;with n as (select n from (values(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) t(n))
, dates as (
  select top (datediff(day, @fromdate, @thrudate)+1) 
      [Date]=convert(date,dateadd(day,row_number() over(order by (select 1))-1,@fromdate))
  from n as deka cross join n as hecto cross join n as kilo
                cross join n as tenK cross join n as hundredK
   order by [Date]
)
select [Date]
from dates;
```

---

Use either like so:

```
select 
    v.Id
  , count(*) as VacationDays
from Vacationtbl v
  inner join Dates d
    on d.Date >= v.[Start]
   and d.Date <= v.[End]
where d.Date >= '20170401'
  and d.Date <= '20170430'
group by v.Id
```

rextester demo (table): http://rextester.com/PLW73242

rextester demo (cte): http://rextester.com/BCY62752

returns:

```
+----+--------------+
| Id | VacationDays |
+----+--------------+
| 01 |            7 |
| 02 |            7 |
+----+--------------+
```

---

Number and Calendar table reference:

- [Generate a set or sequence without loops - 2 - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-2)
- [The "Numbers" or "Tally" Table: What it is and how it replaces a loop - Jeff Moden](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-sql/62867/)
- [Creating a Date Table/Dimension in sql Server 2008 - David Stein](http://www.made2mentor.com/2011/06/creating-a-date-tabledimension-for-sql-server-2008/)
- [Calendar Tables - Why You Need One - David Stein](http://www.made2mentor.com/2011/04/calendar-tables-why-you-need-one/)
- [Creating a date dimension or calendar table in sql Server - Aaron Bertrand](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/)

Comment: The return is correct but I can't use Tally or Dates table. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want only one month and you want to count all days, you can do this with arithmetic.  A separate calendar table is not necessary.  The advantage is performance.

I think this would be easier if SQL Server supported `least()` and `greatest()`, but `case` will do:

```
select id,
       sum(1 + datediff(day, news, newe)) as vacation_days_april
from vactiontbl v cross apply
     (values (case when [start] < '2017-04-01' then cast('2017-04-01' as date) else [start] end),
             (case when [end] >= '2017-05-01' then cast('2017-04-30' as date) else [end] end)
     ) v(news, newe)
where news <= newe
group by id;
```

You can readily extend this to any month:

```
with m as (
      select cast('2017-04-01' as date) as month_start, 
             cast('2017-04-30' as date) as month_end
     )

select id,
       sum(1 + datediff(day, news, newe)) as vacation_days_aprile
from m cross join
     vactiontbl v cross apply
     (values (case when [start] < m.month_start then m.month_start else [start] end),
             (case when [end] >= m.month_end then m.month_end else [end] end)
     ) v(news, newe)
where news <= newe
group by id;
```

You can even use a similar idea to extend to multiple months, with a different row for each user and each month.

Comment: It's dynamic so how do I make it for 12 months and advanced months in the future? I don't use Tally table or Dates tables.  I am newbie so I am looking for something simple hiiiii. Thanks so much!

Comment: I don't know what you mean by dynamic.  Just put the list of dates that you want as rows in the CTE and then add the month start to the `group by` and `select`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
declare @Vacationtbl table(ID int,Startdate date,Enddate date)
 insert into @Vacationtbl VALUES   
(1   ,'04/10/17','04/12/17')
,(1   ,'04/27/17','05/02/17')
,(2   ,'04/13/17','04/15/17')
,(2   ,'04/17/17','04/20/17')
-- somehow convert your input into first day of month
Declare @firstDayofGivenMonth date='2017-04-01'
Declare @LasttDayofGivenMonth date=dateadd(day,-1,dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,@firstDayofGivenMonth)+1,0))

;with CTE as
(
select * 
,case when Startdate<@firstDayofGivenMonth then @firstDayofGivenMonth else Startdate end NewStDT
,case when Enddate>@LasttDayofGivenMonth then @LasttDayofGivenMonth else Enddate end NewEDT
from @Vacationtbl
)

SELECT 
SUM(DATEDIFF(DAY, NewStDT, NewEDT) + 1) AS Days 
FROM 
CTE
GROUP BY 
ID
```